# How to convert Ubuntu WinRAR file to ISO file

Tags: iso

I have the file to install but not ISO, it's WinRAR file. How do I convert it to an ISO file to install?

Comment: WinRAR open .iso files by default. Even if the Ubuntu file have the WinRAR logo it is an .iso image. No need to convert anything ;)

Comment: The file is in ISO format, but since you don't have any application associated with ISO format, it shows as a Winrar file.

Comment: The files are in <code>.ISO</code> format. You don't need to format again.